# Using Machine Learning for Price Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What Machine Learning Method should i Use to predict Prices like Stocks,gold and etc?

I Prefer using Python but I Can't Find the Starting Point as it Seems so Complicated to me and I've no Clue How to Start it.

Comment: start from `Linear Regression` algorithm.

Comment: @Vishal but prices are not Linear so why should i use that?

Comment: Linear regression to predict the continuous variable. Of course, it is not the best, but you said no clue how to start, so just said that build a model in linear regression and keep it as a baseline and then use other algorithms and compare with this base model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about the machine learning method, Regression Method is used for Price prediction as it is used to predict a continuous variable. There are wide range of techniques for regression in machine learning. Starting from simple `linear regression`, `SVR`, `RandomForest`, `CatBoost` to `RNN`. Based on target problem, available datasets and computing resources, one of the algorithms can be used.
Yes, `Python` is the best language to get started into machinbre learning. And definitely, `Linear Regression` is the best way to start for this regression task if you are new. Gradually, you can start exploring other techniques in `scikit-learn` before directly jumping into `RNN`. `Scikit-learn` is the best machine learning library from beginners to professionals.